# Awk, end of line in script

Tags: awk

I'm just making my first attempts with awk and have one, maybe, simple question. I am trying to list a directory and extract some information from the listing based on a string. The bash script I'm trying is:

```
 ls *.hdf > temporary.list
 nom2=`awk 'BEGIN {FS = "." } ; { $1 ~ /'$year$month'/ } { print $2 }' temporary.list `
 file=$year$month.$nom2.hdf 
 file2=$year$month.hdf
```

where year and month change in a for loop (1981 to 1985 and 01 to 12). The temporary.list file is composed of 12 lines like:

```
198201.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198202.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198203.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198204.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198205.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198206.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198207.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198208.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198209.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198210.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198211.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
198212.s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf
```

I want to select files depending on year-month. The problem is that my awk sentence does not seem to get different lines as different registers, I suppose. The output of the script is:

```
nom2 = h s04m1pfv51-bsst h s04m1pfv51-bsst h s04m1pfv51-bsst h
s04m1pfv51-bsst h s04m1pfv51-bsst h s04m1pfv51-bsst h s04m1pfv51-bsst
s04m1pfv51-bsst s04m1pfv51-bsst s04m1pfv51-bsst s04m1pfv51-bsst
s04m1pfv51-bsst 

file = 198201.h s04m1pfv51-bsst h s04m1pfv51-bsst h
s04m1pfv51-bsst h s04m1pfv51-bsst h s04m1pfv51-bsst h s04m1pfv51-bsst
h s04m1pfv51-bsst s04m1pfv51-bsst s04m1pfv51-bsst s04m1pfv51-bsst
s04m1pfv51-bsst s04m1pfv51-bsst.hdf 

file2= 198201.hdf
```

Maybe is some simple syntax error, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the output that you WANT to get from your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `awk` the variables you need it to know about.
To pass a variable to `awk`, use `-v` for each one.

```
awk -v y="$year" -v m="$month" 'BEGIN { FS = "." } $1 == y m { print $2 }' file
```

`awk` vars can then be used directly, no `$` needed.
as with `print` the space between them will be ignored, a real space would have to be quoted.
So the way it is now, it checks if the first field (`$1`) exactly matches (`==`) '`y m`' which is expanded to '`${year}${month}`'. If the match happens then the 2nd field (`$2`) is printed.

---

keep in mind that `awk` logic blocks are in the form

```
condition { action [; action ..] }
```

note no curly braces around `condition`
you also don't need `;` between blocks, only between actions, but they don't hurt either.
so, `{ $1 ~ /'$year$month'/ }` will do nothing the way it is written.

---

having said all that, I would go with pure `Bash` for what you're doing:

```
while IFS='.' read -r ym f e
do 
    printf '%8s: %s\n' "year"  "${ym%??}"   \
                       "month" "${ym#????}" \
                       "file"  "$f"         \
                       "ext"   "$e"
done < file
```

Comment: The `{ $1 ~ /'$year$month'/ }` does do something. The first single quote *ends* a single quoted string so that the `$year$month` substitution works...

Comment: Pasing variables is ok in my script, I just showed the awk part. The point is that _nom2_ should show only one value, coresponding to the year and month and what I get is **nom2 s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b s04m1pfv50-bsst-16b** showing the 12 months value

Comment: If I add grep $year$month to the directory listing (temporary.list is then a single line file) then it works and properly extracts the values I need. But I think this should be done with awk.

Comment: @jens right, and that is the way **not** to pass vars to `awk`

Comment: @pacomet right, because the condition acts like an empty `if` statement and `print $2` prints unconditionally. I told you on my answer: `{ $1 ~ /'$year$month'/ }` is like `if ($1 ~ /'$year$month'/) /*empty*/;`

Comment: Thanks for your explanations about awk, I've managed to get the script running.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad habit to parse lists of files the way you're doing it in your bash script, since it's incompatible with a number of special characters that might appear in a filename.  Like rules of grammar, you should break the rules only if you know them well.  :)  A `for` loop is a better construct for handling files:

```
#!/bin/bash

year=1982
month=9

for filename in $(printf "%04d%02d" "$year" "$month").*.hdf; do
  nom2=${filename#*.}
  nom2=${nom2%.*}
  file2=${filename%%.*}.hdf
  printf "file=%s\nnom2=%s\nfile2=%s\n\n" "$filename" "$nom2" "$file2"
done
```

Is that what you're looking for?  Note that parameter expansion using `%` and `#` works in traditional bourne shell as well as bash, so it's extremely portable.

If you REALLY want to use awk, you've still got lots of options.

```
#!/bin/bash

year=1982
month=9

for filename in $(printf "%04d%02d" "$year" "$month").*.hdf; do
  nom2=$(awk -vym="^$year$month." -vf="$filename" 'BEGIN{if(f~ym){sub(/\..*/,"",f);print f}}')
  file="$nom2.hdf"
  printf "file=%s\nnom2=%s\nfile2=%s\n\n" "$filename" "$nom2" "$file2"
done
```

Note that using `printf` to format the date allows you to handle single-digit months with a leading zero, with minimal effort.

Comment: I can't figure out how sub works here. It also warns of an error in the double quote _/,",f_ close to sub.

Comment: Wups, typo (now fixed) - I missed a quote in `sub()`.  The idea is that it looks for a pattern starting with the first dot and going to the end of the line, replaces it all with an empty string.  And the workspace it's doing this in is the "f" variable, set with `-v` earlier.